# Calling a function within a loop

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am trying to a simple addition function that will take a number `x` from an array an and add a variable `i` to it, which is the iteration variable inside the for loop.  Instead of adding each variable individually and producing the output of :

> 3, 2, 7

it produces values of

> 3, 5, 13.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int add(int x[], int y);
int main(void) {
    int i;
    int a[3] = {3, 1, 5};
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("%d \t", i);
        printf("%d, %d, equals %d \n", a[i], i,  add(a[i], i));
    }
    return 0;
}
int add(int x[], int y){
    return x+y;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
int add(int x, int y){
    return x+y;
}
```

Comment: @user3727944, if the answer worked for you then try to accept it.

Comment: [to OP] You're very right, but instead of adding _only_ the modified code, try to explain a little about the _reason_ for doing so. It helps everyone reading the answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

In your function definition,

```
int add(int x[], int y){
```

`int x[]` expects an array to be passed as the argument. By calling that with

```
      add(a[i], i)
```

you're making multiple mistakes, like

- passing an `int` value where `int *` is expected, so a wrong and implicit conversion from `int` to `int *` is talking place.
- Inside `add()`, `x` is of type `int *`. So, by saying `return x+y;`, you're essentially again (wrongly) converting a *pointer* to `int` type.

Here, it seems, you need only one `int` variable. not an array. Change it (both declaration and definition) to

```
int add(int x, int y){
```

**Suggestion:** Turn up the compiler warnings and pay heed to them. For example, with the `-Wall` option enabled, you would have received a warning saying

> warning: passing argument 1 of ‘add’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
>
> > ```
> > printf("%d, %d, equals %d \n", a[i], i,  add(a[i], i));
> >                                              ^
> > ```

and

> expected `int *` but argument is of type `int`
>
> > ```
> > int add(int x[], int y);
> > ```

and,

> warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast
>
> > ```
> >   return x+y;
> >   ^
> > ```

Answer (score 1):

You are using array as an argument. Please try below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int add(int x, int y);
int main(void) {
    int i;
    int a[3] = {3, 1, 5};
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("%d \t", i);
        printf("%d, %d, equals %d \n", a[i], i,  add(a[i], i));
    }
    return 0;
}
int add(int x, int y){
    return x+y;
}
```